# the calling of activity in intent crashes app

Tags: android, android-intent

hi guys this is my code in splash screen activity on below line-

```
i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
```

i dont know why but app crashes and log doesnt show any error for that i wonder..

on debugger mode my control jumps on `noClassDefFound` and `invocationTargetExceptio` after above line of code[image]. `i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);` after this line of code debugger goes to here- 
[image]

and then here->[image]
and my manifest file is-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="15"
android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name1"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.GCMIntentService" />
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/app_name1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.HomeMainScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.LiveVideo"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/rastiyaujjala"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.PoliticalMenu"
        android:label="@string/political"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.AgricultureMenu"
        android:label="@string/agriculture"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.SportMenu"
        android:label="@string/sport"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.HomeDetails"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Home"
        android:label="Home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.National"
        android:label="@string/national" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.National2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/national" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.International2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/internatation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Business2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/business" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Rajya2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/business" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Political2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/political" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Technology2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/technology" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Lifestyle2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/lifestyle" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Rashifal2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/rashifal" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.Sports2"
        android:icon="@drawable/mono"
        android:label="@string/sport" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.VideoPageFragment"
        android:label="@string/sport"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <!--
    <receiver android:name="com.personagraph.sensor.service.StartupReceiver"> <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/> </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.personagraph.sensor.service.SensorService"> 
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.personagraph.SensorService" /> 
       </intent-filter>
    </service>  


    -->
</application>
```

and this is logcat-

```
    11-21 15:07:49.924: D/SurfaceFlinger(158): SurfaceFlingerWatchdog:ERROR: open /dev/RT_Monitor failed.
11-21 15:07:50.191: W/ActivityManager(670): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41f71d28 u0 com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps/.SplashScreen t51 f}
11-21 15:07:50.191: I/libPerfService(670): 1: set: 2
11-21 15:07:50.191: E/(670): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
11-21 15:07:50.191: E/(670): error : 2, No such file or directory
11-21 15:07:50.193: D/InputReader(670): InputReader:: getSwitchState lock 
11-21 15:07:50.193: D/InputReader(670): InputReader::getStateLocked:: return 
11-21 15:07:50.195: D/dalvikvm(670): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
11-21 15:07:50.195: D/dalvikvm(670): create new thread
11-21 15:07:50.195: D/dalvikvm(670): new thread created
11-21 15:07:50.195: D/dalvikvm(670): update thread list
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: interp stack at 0x57b4d000
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: created from interp
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: adding to list
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): start new thread
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: notify debugger
11-21 15:07:50.196: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71 (Thread-248): calling run()
11-21 15:07:50.196: I/libPerfService(670): 1: set: 1
11-21 15:07:50.196: E/(670): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
11-21 15:07:50.196: E/(670): error : 2, No such file or directory
11-21 15:07:50.197: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: exiting
11-21 15:07:50.197: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: detach (group=0x418ccce0)
11-21 15:07:50.197: D/NetworkPolicy(670): onRecv: MSG_FOREGROUND_ACTIVITIES_CHANGED pid:uid:act=922:10011:true
11-21 15:07:50.197: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: removing from list
11-21 15:07:50.197: D/dalvikvm(670): threadid=71: bye!
11-21 15:07:50.198: V/NetworkStats(670): setKernelCounterSet uid=10011 set=1
11-21 15:07:50.198: D/ConnectivityService(670): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10011, uidRules=0)
11-21 15:07:50.201: D/OpenGLRenderer(922): Flushing caches (mode 0)
11-21 15:07:50.205: V/ActivityThread(922): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{41bb01e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}} finished=false
11-21 15:07:50.206: D/Launcher3(922): Launcher, (Launcher)onStart: this = com.android.launcher3.Launcher@41bd50d0
11-21 15:07:50.206: D/Launcher3(922): Launcher, (Launcher)onResume: mRestoring = false, mOnResumeNeedsLoad = false,mOrientationChanged = false,mPagesAreRecreated = false, this = com.android.launcher3.Launcher@41bd50d0
11-21 15:07:50.207: D/Launcher3(922): SearchButtonExt, getSearchButtonExt: context = com.android.launcher3.Launcher@41bd50d0, mSearchButtonExt = com.mediatek.launcher3.ext.DefaultSearchButton@41c5fb88
11-21 15:07:50.207: D/Launcher3(922): DefaultSearchButtonExt, default needUpdateSearchButtonResource called.
11-21 15:07:50.207: D/Launcher3(922): Launcher, updateGlobalSearchIcon: needUpdate = true,activityName = ComponentInfo{com.android.quicksearchbox/com.android.quicksearchbox.SearchActivity}
11-21 15:07:50.211: D/asset(922): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
11-21 15:07:50.217: D/ActivityThread(922): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41bb01e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}}
11-21 15:07:50.217: V/ActivityThread(922): Resume ActivityRecord{41bb01e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
11-21 15:07:50.217: V/ActivityThread(922): Resuming ActivityRecord{41bb01e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}} with isForward=false
11-21 15:07:50.218: V/PhoneWindow(922): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{41c7a720 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41bedad0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-320,480}
11-21 15:07:50.218: V/ActivityThread(922): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{41bb01e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970 {com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}}
11-21 15:07:50.219: D/ActivityThread(922): ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41baf970
11-21 15:07:50.221: I/BufferQueue(158): [unnamed-158-314](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue
11-21 15:07:50.221: I/BufferQueue(158): [unnamed-158-314](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:-1,c:158) consumerConnect consumer=(158:/system/bin/surfaceflinger) controlledByApp=false
11-21 15:07:50.222: I/BufferQueue(158): [unnamed-158-314](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:-1,c:158) setConsumerName: unnamed-158-314
11-21 15:07:50.222: I/GLConsumer(158): [unnamed-158-314](this:0xb8a15d20,api:0) GLConsumer
11-21 15:07:50.222: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:-1,c:158) setConsumerName: com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher
11-21 15:07:50.222: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:-1,c:158) setDefaultBufferSize: w=320, h=480
11-21 15:07:50.225: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:0,p:922,c:158) connect: api=1 producer=(922:com.android.launcher3) producerControlledByApp=true
11-21 15:07:50.226: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) new GraphicBuffer needed
11-21 15:07:50.226: D/BufferQueue(158):     [OLD] gb:NULL
11-21 15:07:50.226: I/GraphicBuffer(158): allocate buffer (w:320 h:480 f:1) handle(0xb8a08830) err(0)
11-21 15:07:50.226: W/GraphicBufferExtra_hal(158): gralloc extra device setBufInfo(...) is not supported
11-21 15:07:50.226: I/BufferQueue(158):     [NEW] gb=0xb89ff110, handle=0xb8a08830, w=320, h=480, s=320, fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.226: D/GraphicBuffer(922): create handle(0x53617000) (w:320, h:480, f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.227: D/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) cancelBuffer: slot=0
11-21 15:07:50.227: I/MaliEGL(922): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
11-21 15:07:50.227: I/MaliEGL(922): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
11-21 15:07:50.227: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) setBufferCount: count=4
11-21 15:07:50.227: I/GraphicBuffer(158): free buffer (w:320 h:480 f:1) handle(0xb8a08830)
11-21 15:07:50.227: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffff
11-21 15:07:50.227: D/GraphicBuffer(922): close handle(0x53617000) (w:320 h:480 f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.228: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) new GraphicBuffer needed
11-21 15:07:50.228: D/BufferQueue(158):     [OLD] gb:NULL
11-21 15:07:50.229: I/GraphicBuffer(158): allocate buffer (w:320 h:480 f:1) handle(0xb8a08830) err(0)
11-21 15:07:50.229: W/GraphicBufferExtra_hal(158): gralloc extra device setBufInfo(...) is not supported
11-21 15:07:50.229: I/BufferQueue(158):     [NEW] gb=0xb89ff110, handle=0xb8a08830, w=320, h=480, s=320, fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.229: D/GraphicBuffer(922): create handle(0x53617000) (w:320, h:480, f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.229: D/OpenGLRenderer(922): setViewport 320x480 <0x544b7010>
11-21 15:07:50.236: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c010002
11-21 15:07:50.237: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c010002
11-21 15:07:50.238: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c010302
11-21 15:07:50.239: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c010302
11-21 15:07:50.242: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9b000000
11-21 15:07:50.243: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9b010100
11-21 15:07:50.244: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9b030300
11-21 15:07:50.245: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9b040400
11-21 15:07:50.261: V/WallpaperManagerService(670): Visibility changed from WMS : true
11-21 15:07:50.262: V/WallpaperService(739): Visibility change in com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine@41dafe58: 1
11-21 15:07:50.262: V/WallpaperService(739): onVisibilityChanged(true): com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine@41dafe58
11-21 15:07:50.266: D/PowerManagerService(670): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=1103383632 [ActivityManager-Launch], flags=0x0, total_time=576ms
11-21 15:07:50.266: D/PowerManagerNotifier(670): onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="ActivityManager-Launch", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=670, workSource=null
11-21 15:07:50.266: D/PowerManagerService(670): updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x0
11-21 15:07:50.267: D/PowerManagerService(670): newScreenState = 2
11-21 15:07:50.267: D/PowerManagerDisplayController(670): requestPowerState: screenState=2, useProximitySensor=false, forceProximitySensorEnable=false, forceWakeUpEnable=false, screenBrightness=146, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, useAutoBrightness=false, useEcoBrightness=false, blockScreenOn=false, waitForNegativeProximity=false
11-21 15:07:50.267: I/PowerManagerService(670): setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
11-21 15:07:50.267: D/PowerManagerService(670): updateScreenStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, newScreenState=2, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x0, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true
11-21 15:07:50.267: D/PowerManagerService(670): Releasing suspend blocker "PowerManagerService.WakeLocks".
11-21 15:07:50.267: D/PowerManagerService(670): handleSandman: canDream=true, mWakefulness=Awake
11-21 15:07:50.273: D/PhoneStatusBar(739): setSystemUiVisibility vis=40000000 mask=ffffffff oldVal=0 newVal=40000000 diff=40000000
11-21 15:07:50.274: D/BarTransitions.PhoneStatusBarView(739): MODE_OPAQUE -> MODE_TRANSLUCENT animate=true
11-21 15:07:50.274: D/BarTransitions.PhoneStatusBarView(739): applyModeBackground oldMode=MODE_OPAQUE newMode=MODE_TRANSLUCENT animate=true
11-21 15:07:50.672: D/ActivityManager(670): ACT-IDLE_NOW_MSG from windowsVisible() for idle: ActivityRecord{41f24108 u0 com.android.launcher3/.Launcher t1}
11-21 15:07:50.676: D/NetworkPolicy(670): onRecv: MSG_FOREGROUND_ACTIVITIES_CHANGED pid:uid:act=5880:10135:false
11-21 15:07:50.677: V/NetworkStats(670): setKernelCounterSet uid=10135 set=0
11-21 15:07:50.677: D/ConnectivityService(670): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10135, uidRules=0)
11-21 15:07:50.731: I/BufferQueue(158): [Application Error: com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps](this:0xb8a0e650,id:313,api:2,p:670,c:158) new GraphicBuffer needed
11-21 15:07:50.731: D/BufferQueue(158):     [OLD] gb:NULL
11-21 15:07:50.731: I/GraphicBuffer(158): allocate buffer (w:320 h:127 f:1) handle(0xb89eed88) err(0)
11-21 15:07:50.731: W/GraphicBufferExtra_hal(158): gralloc extra device setBufInfo(...) is not supported
11-21 15:07:50.731: I/BufferQueue(158):     [NEW] gb=0xb89feea0, handle=0xb89eed88, w=320, h=127, s=320, fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.732: D/GraphicBuffer(670): create handle(0x546f1b70) (w:320, h:127, f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.737: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020001
11-21 15:07:50.737: W/ResourceType(922): No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020001
11-21 15:07:50.739: I/BufferQueue(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a1cd00,id:314,api:1,p:922,c:158) new GraphicBuffer needed
11-21 15:07:50.739: D/BufferQueue(158):     [OLD] gb:NULL
11-21 15:07:50.739: I/GraphicBuffer(158): allocate buffer (w:320 h:480 f:1) handle(0xb8a157d8) err(0)
11-21 15:07:50.739: W/GraphicBufferExtra_hal(158): gralloc extra device setBufInfo(...) is not supported
11-21 15:07:50.739: I/BufferQueue(158):     [NEW] gb=0xb8a06e60, handle=0xb8a157d8, w=320, h=480, s=320, fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.740: D/GraphicBuffer(922): create handle(0x53ae5c90) (w:320, h:480, f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.746: I/GLConsumer(158): [Application Error: com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps](this:0xb8a150a0,api:2) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)]
11-21 15:07:50.746: D/GLConsumer(158):     GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb89feea0 handle=0xb89eed88 fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.746: D/GLConsumer(158):     EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000004
11-21 15:07:50.748: I/SurfaceFlinger(158): [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:50.149673,dur:1016.96,max:152.32,min:13.61
11-21 15:07:50.761: I/GLConsumer(158): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8a15d20,api:1) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)]
11-21 15:07:50.761: D/GLConsumer(158):     GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8a06e60 handle=0xb8a157d8 fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.761: D/GLConsumer(158):     EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000008
11-21 15:07:50.924: D/SurfaceFlinger(158): SurfaceFlingerWatchdog:ERROR: open /dev/RT_Monitor failed.
11-21 15:07:50.943: I/BufferQueue(158): [Application Error: com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps](this:0xb8a0e650,id:313,api:2,p:670,c:158) new GraphicBuffer needed
11-21 15:07:50.943: D/BufferQueue(158):     [OLD] gb:NULL
11-21 15:07:50.943: I/GraphicBuffer(158): allocate buffer (w:320 h:127 f:1) handle(0xb8a02578) err(0)
11-21 15:07:50.943: W/GraphicBufferExtra_hal(158): gralloc extra device setBufInfo(...) is not supported
11-21 15:07:50.943: I/BufferQueue(158):     [NEW] gb=0xb8a025f8, handle=0xb8a02578, w=320, h=127, s=320, fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.944: D/GraphicBuffer(670): create handle(0x52a4ccf0) (w:320, h:127, f:1)
11-21 15:07:50.947: I/BufferQueue(158): [Application Error: com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps](this:0xb8a0e650,id:313,api:2,p:670,c:158) [queue] fps:1.76, dur:1133.76, max:921.23, min:212.53
11-21 15:07:50.958: I/GLConsumer(158): [Application Error: com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps](this:0xb8a150a0,api:2) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)]
11-21 15:07:50.958: D/GLConsumer(158):     GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8a025f8 handle=0xb8a02578 fmt=1
11-21 15:07:50.958: D/GLConsumer(158):     EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000009
11-21 15:07:50.960: I/BufferQueue(158): [FrameBufferSurface_0](this:0xb89e31a8,id:0,api:1,p:158,c:158) [release] fps:44.28, dur:1106.62, max:196.84, min:14.77
11-21 15:07:50.960: I/BufferQueue(158): [FrameBufferSurface_0](this:0xb89e31a8,id:0,api:1,p:158,c:158) [queue] fps:44.27, dur:1106.72, max:197.03, min:14.76
11-21 15:07:51.159: D/WifiStateMachine(670): ConnectedState{ when=-4ms what=131155 arg1=4 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41e870f8} }
11-21 15:07:51.160: D/WifiStateMachine(670): L2ConnectedState{ when=-4ms what=131155 arg1=4 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {41e870f8} }
11-21 15:07:51.160: D/WifiHW(670): enter -->wifi_send_command cmd=IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL
11-21 15:07:51.160: D/wpa_supplicant(848): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
11-21 15:07:51.160: D/wpa_supplicant(848): wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
11-21 15:07:51.175: D/wpa_supplicant(848): nl80211: survey data missing!
11-21 15:07:51.176: D/WifiHW(670): leave --> reply=RSSI=-61
11-21 15:07:51.176: D/WifiHW(670): LINKSPEED=54
11-21 15:07:51.176: D/WifiHW(670): NOISE=9999
11-21 15:07:51.176: D/WifiHW(670): FREQUENCY=2462
11-21 15:07:51.176: D/wifi(670): doStringCommand, buf IFNAME=wlan0 SIGNAL_POLL
```

Comment: have you declare your MainActivity in manifest ?

Comment: Declare MainActivity.java in manifest first

Comment: already declared it....

Comment: `<activity
            android:name="com.yash.rastiyaujjalaapps.MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/mono"
            android:label="@string/app_name1" >
        </activity>`

Comment: clean project and then try to build

Comment: i tryed everything clean the project restarted the eclipse but no use of it

Comment: can you post your `MainAcitivty` source code?

Comment: check statement in onCreate().... check the statement setContent(R.layout.act); ........... check the id is correctly written.... may be this is problem for invocationTargetException..... check,,,... can you post the complete log so that we will check.

Comment: @nilesh as it is not going to main activity,the problem arises before the startactivity(),

Comment: try absolute path in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Post your error message

Comment: i have posted my logcat output but i didnt find any error there

Comment: @nilesh tried that too...

Comment: @sud I think you're new in android?

Comment: why? what happened?did i made some silly mistake in code?

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys thank for all of your answers i did some steps and my problem gets solved, its sounds strange but i did some following task and problem vanishes like magick, i dont knw which part worked but i am sharing some-

1. i removed my appcompat and then imported it freshly then restart android.
2. i newly imports all the jar files i required
3. my declaration of intent  `Intent i`  and my `i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);` and `startActivity(i)` all those lines i surround all of them with try catch and whoa its works. thank you guys for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be due to one of following two reasons:-

1.) There is no MainActivity.class file or
2.) If it is, it may not be declared in manifest.xml

if it is created, just check your manifest.xml file and see whether it is written over there or not and if it not there just the the following lines to the manifest file 
`<activity android:name=.MainActivity
android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to "Properties" of the project.
2. Select "Java Build Path"
3. Select "Order and Export" Tab
4. You should see the selected project's "src" and "gen" paths and dependencies here.
5. The order how they listed were first "src" and then "gen" path
6. Switch them, so that "gen" folder is build before the "src"

gen - automated code in project (from dependencies and references)

src - source code in project

No need to restart the Eclipse.

Comment: yeah it was , i arranged them in the manner i said but not working

Answer (score 0):

SplashScreen.this is the Launcher activity change in the AndroidMainfest.xml file.
 ..
I think this will help you